# inconsistent behaviour with syncfusion charts while iterating over the items in Angular

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion charts in my application.
i have implemented a sample in below stackblitz link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng8kss?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

if i am printing the chart one time it is working fine

**problem: while iterating through the items the chart is not showing as the number of items in the tempArray (please see the first line code in app.component.html)**
Please let me know if anyone know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve your requirement by passing the **parent id** in chart **print** method, so that the entire charts can be printed as you desired.

**print.html**

```
<div class="col-md-9" id="print1">
    <div *ngFor="let item of tempArray;let i = index">
       // Other chart configurations
    </div>
</div>
```

**print.component.ts**

```
// Getting instance of chart

@ViewChild('pie')
public pie: AccumulationChartComponent;

public mode(e: Event): void {
    // Passing the parent id
    this.pie.print("print1");
}
```

[Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzvqvt-zw8uaj?file=print.html)

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Dharani.